# Extracting Relevant Information Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to pull information from several text files located in a folder, put them on individual worksheets, and keep only relevant information from each worksheet. I'm having problems deleting the unwanted rows, I'm colouring the rows so I can sort the relevant information. Code provided below. Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long
 Dim myCell As Range

iPath = "C:\Users\dbutler\Desktop\Folder_1\" 'Imports the text files from Folder address  
iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.txt")
Do While Len(iFile)
Sheets.Add , Sheets(Sheets.Count), , iPath & iFile
iFile = Dir
Loop

'Selects every sheet but Command
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Command" Then

        lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        'filter and delete all rows
        For Each myCell In rng

'Delete rows if they do not contain the below values
            If Not (myCell Like "*10570*" Or _
                myCell Like "*10571*" Or _
                myCell Like "*10572*" Or _
                myCell Like "*11503*" Or _
                myCell Like "*10308*" Or _
                myCell Like "*11324*" Or _
                myCell Like "*18368*" Or _
                myCell Like "*13369*" Or _
                myCell Like "*15369*" Or _
                myCell Like "*10814*" Or _
                myCell Like "*22306*" Or _
                myCell Like "*12009*" Or _
                myCell Like "*15088*" Or _
                myCell Like "*72216*") Then

                myCell.EntireRow.Delete


            End If
            Next myCell


End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Too many rows deleted? Error message? Anything else?

Comment: It doesn't delete the irrelevant information, or anything at all. if I change the myCell.EntireRow.Delete to myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0), it does colour the rows, so I was wondering is there a different procedure to deleting the rows. Initially I used an Autofilter function but it would not allow me have more than two criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.entirerow.delete` is correct. I think your problem lies in the shift of data when you start deleting from the top.

Try to use

```
    For I = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        Set mycell = ws.Cells(I, 1)
```

instead of your for each loop. (change the next statement to `Next I`) to start deleting from the bottom.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a million